# I can't load an .el package on emacs

Tags: emacs

So I downloaded an .el file, I put it on the `~/.emacs.d/elpa/` folder, but it won't appear on the `M-x list-packages`. How do I make it appear there or how can I install this file/package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of installing an Emacs package: either type `M-x list-packages` and install it from the list, letting Emacs download it for you, or download the package yourself and install it with `M-x package-install-file`.

## Installing from a package archive

In the first case, note that there are several different package archives.  The default value for the variable `package-archives` only contains [GNU ELPA](https://elpa.gnu.org/), but most people want to add [MELPA](http://melpa.org/#/getting-started) to that list since it has more packages.  To do that, you need to add the following to your `.emacs` file (copied from the MELPA web page):

```lisp
(require 'package) ;; You might already have this line
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(when (< emacs-major-version 24)
  ;; For important compatibility libraries like cl-lib
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))
(package-initialize) ;; You might already have this line
```

After that, typing `M-x list-packages` should list more packages than you'll ever need :)

## Installing from a downloaded file

There are two types of packages: single-file packages and multi-file packages.  The former can be downloaded as a single `.el` file, while the latter are distributed as tarballs (`.tar`).  Both types can be installed with `M-x package-install-file`.

Note that not every `.el` file can be installed as a package.  The comments at the beginning of the file need to follow a certain convention, documented in the [Simple packages](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Simple-Packages.html) node of the Emacs Lisp reference manual.

---

That leaves the possibility that the `.el` file you've downloaded is not installable as a package.  In that case, you should put it in some other directory (`~/.emacs.d/elpa` is meant for installed packages only), add that directory to the `load-path` variable, and `require` the package.  If you have `foo.el` and put it in `~/path/to/foo`, it would look something like this:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/path/to/foo")
(require 'foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

An `.el` file is not a package. Installing it via ELPA is probably vastly preferrable to manually downloading a static `.el` file; perhaps the maintainer has a home page with ELPA (or Marmalade, etc) instructions.

In particular, a package will receive updates as they are made available, so you will not be forever stuck on an increasingly obsolete, unmanaged version (though quiet, fully automatic updates are not yet available or feasible, AFAICT).

But if you have to get by with just the file you already downloaded, you can put it pretty much anywhere you like, as long as that directory is included in the `load-path`. Manually mucking with the `elpa` directory is a bad idea, though; put it somewhere else.

Look for comments near the top of the file for any additional instructions; any autoloads, for example, will probably have to be configured separately, and usually completely manually.

This used to be how you always did things in older versions of Emacs, so you should find that the Internet is still practically bulging with guides and tutorials which explain the finer details of this mechanism, if this answer alone isn't sufficient.

Comment: For example, I read:
"You can install zenburn with the following command:

M-x package-install zenburn-theme"
Then when I try to do that, it says there is no match.

Comment: @144Ky You need to to add the necessary archive, most likely MELPA. `M-x customize-variable package-archives`.

Comment: @144Ky Also, it is not possible that you truly hate Emacs.

Comment: @LeonGrapenthin Don't rule out the impossible. There are even people who (think they) like Windows.

Comment: As predicted, the project has simple, straightforward installation instructions for both scenarios. For the packaged version, you'll need to enable either of the MELPA or Marmalade package repository, which are not included out of the box with many Emacsen; the instructions are at https://github.com/bbatsov/zenburn-emacs/blob/master/README.md#installation

Comment: The canonical directory for elisp that is not in a package is `~/.emacs.d/lisp/` (`(concat user-emacs-directory "lisp/")`).  Unfortunately. this is not in the `load-path` by default.  It's much better to put things in there than `~/.emacs.d/`.

Comment: This is nonsense, IMHO: "*Installing it via ELPA is probably vastly preferable to manually downloading a static .el file*." Vastly preferable? I don't think so.

Comment: @Drew How so? Especially for a casual / reluctant user, using the package manager is much easier immediately, and it also simplifies long-term maintainability enormously.

Comment: I created a pull request to hopefully clarify the documentation a little bit; https://github.com/bbatsov/zenburn-emacs/pull/229

Comment: @tripleee: For a casual/reluctant user the pkg mgr can be easier to use, yes. That is different from "*probably vastly preferable*" for everyone.